# Checkup for a block of memory, containing a repeated single byte

Tags: c++

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166035/how-to-efficiently-compare-a-block-of-memory-to-a-single-byte) on SO, because I needed something similar. There are eight answers to it, and I wasn't satisfied with any of them - so I've written my own solution (please see below). It's in C++, so I decided not to add the ninth answer to the C-oriented question.

The solution tries to use the multibyte comparison, which is presumably supported by hardware. I used to call the `compare` function with the `unsigned long` template parameter. The byte-to-byte comparison might be needed only in the end if and only if the length of the memory block is not divisible by the `sizeof(T)`.

```
template <typename T>
inline auto repeatedByte(unsigned char const B)
{
  T res = 0;
  memset(&res, B, sizeof(T));
  return res;
}

template <typename T>
auto compare(const void* const PTR, unsigned char const B, unsigned const N)
{
  if (N > 0)
  {
    auto const value = repeatedByte<T>(B);
    auto const n0 = N / sizeof(T);
    auto i0 = 0U;
    auto ptr0 = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(PTR);
    while (i0 < n0 && *ptr0 == value) {++i0; ++ptr0;}
    if (i0 >= n0)
    {
      if (N % sizeof(T) > 0)
      {
        auto i1 = n0 * sizeof(T);
        auto ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ptr0);
        while (i1 < N && *ptr1 == B) {++i1; ++ptr1;}
        return (i1 >= N);
      }
      else
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE.** I've implemented *all* the @GSliepen suggestions how to improve this code - especially about the data alignment, which looks most critical. All the updates can be found in [this](https://github.com/alekseYY/Checkup-for-a-block-of-memory-containing-a-repeated-single-byte) Github repository.

Comment: I've added an answer to the linked SO question, which might provide a route to a simpler function with good performance (accounting for optimal alignment, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This doesn't account for alignment

Consider that `PTR` might not be aligned correctly for a `T`. You have to account for this first, for example by comparing the first few bytes individually until `PTR` is suitably aligned.

Depending on `T` and your CPU architecture, misaligned reads might either work fine, work but be much slower, crash your program, or worst of all: give you the wrong results.

## Remove unnecessary `if`-statements

It's very unlikely anyone will call your function with `N` set to `0`. The `if`-statement at the start is being evaluated every time the function calls, so wastes a few unnecessary cycles, and it makes the code look more complex. But your loops are already handling the case of `N = 0` correctly, so I would just remove that outer `if`-statement entirely.

You might do the same with `if (N % sizeof(T) > 0)`, although there it's of course more likely to avoid the inner loop, but consider that the loop itself would exit immediately after the first check of `i0 < N`, so there is very little to no performance loss to run it even if `N % sizeof(T) == 0`.

Finally, you can remove some unnecessary indentation by changing the order of the `if` and `else` branches, for example you can write:

```
if (i0 < n0) {
    return false;
}
// no else
…
```

## Use `static_cast<>()` where possible

`static_cast<>()` is the safest way to cast things. Use it where possible. Casting any pointer type to and from `void*` is possible with `static_cast<>()`, so there is no need for `reinterpret_cast<>()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I forgot about alignment! I'll fix that. Happy New Year!

Comment: I've updated my code and put it in the Github - just not to make your answer irrelevant. Thanks again!